# What are the dimensions of the A320's wingtip fences?

Tags: wing, airbus-a320, winglets

Does anyone know the size (relative to the wing) or have a schematic draw of these wingtip fences?

[image]

Comment: I wasn't sure what you meant by "A320-380" so I simplified the question to just the A320. If I got it wrong, please feel free to edit again to make it clear which model(s) you're interested in.

Comment: Did you find the dimensions of the wingtip fences as I am looking for them too!

Answer (score 2):

Dimensional information can be found on Airbus's [Airport and Maintenance Planning Documents](https://www.airbus.com/aircraft/support-services/airport-operations-and-technical-data/aircraft-characteristics.html) for the entire product range.

You will have to do a little digging and calculation to find the sizes of the wingtip devices but they are there.

Specifically, on the A320, subject 2-3-0 lists the height of both of the bottom and top of the wingtip fences relative to the ground, and 2-2-0 provides dimensions from the top.

Comment: ["Your answer is in another castle"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer), or please provide a quote from the linked source that sufficiently answers the question.

Comment: Sharklet height is 2.43 meters according to the source above FIGURE-2-2-0-991-004-A01 and FIGURE-2-3-0-991-004-A01 lists the wing tip fence lower tip above ground as W2 = 3.78 and upper tip as W1 = 4.76 - so 0.98 meters....
Not very accurate through